# How to use URL Routing with database

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, url-routing

I'm building an Asp/.Net Web Application and I don't know how to create a URL Routing for make `/blog/title-of-the-post` redirect to `post.aspx?id=2`.

I already have on my database the column URL (and I want to use that).

Everywhere on my code for redirect to my post I already use the URL column (usign `<%#Eval("URL") %>`) but of course, does not work cause I do not have a Routing.

Comment: Why not `/blog/$id/title-of-the-post`?

Comment: i prefer `/blog/title-of-the-post`, i don't think the code is going to be too much different from `/blog/$id/title-of-the-post`

Comment: Yeah it was just a sidenote. More ontopic: I don't understand your problem, can you explain your question a bit better?

Comment: I don't know how to create a URL Routing for make `/blog/title-of-the-post` redirect to `post.aspx?id=2`.